# Cannot Load a Specific RSS Feed to Wordpress

Tags: rss

The current problem that I have is I cannot load RSS feed from VOA news. I tried different plugin and jetpack with no avail.
for example, VOA RSS from `https://www.voanews.com/api/zq$omekvi_` will only show the url without the feed in my widget. is there any proper way to load it? I try it in my joomla website, and the result is displayed just fine.
Other RSS feed from different source works, tho.

Answer (score 0):

This website looks like it filters WordPress user-agent then you need to set another user-agent to read this RSS feed like this :

```
$url = "https://www.voanews.com/api/zq\$omekvi_";

$args = [
    "user-agent" => $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],
];

$response = wp_remote_get($url, $args);
```

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure how to. Do you mind to give quick guidance?

Comment: Other way to fix this without modifying the php file is by funneling the feeds through feedburner. It is being displayed correctly now. But thank you for the answer.